# Trying to change the border-color with jQuery .click event

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the color of the border on the bottom of the 5 div's class="Hoofdstuk" using a .click event from jQuery. As you can see in the following link:

[casperjonker.site50.net](http://casperjonker.site50.net/)

As you can see it is not working. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="Hoofdstuk" id="Introductie"></div>
<div class="Hoofdstuk" id="Content"></div>
<div class="Hoofdstuk" id="Interactie"></div>
<div class="Hoofdstuk" id="FrontEnd"></div>
<div class="Hoofdstuk" id="Projecten"></div>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('.Hoofdstuk').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        'width': '55em'
    }).siblings().animate({
        'width': '5em'
    }).css({
        'border-color': '#ffba00'
    }).siblings().css({
        'border-color': '#333'
    })
});
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
.Hoofdstuk {
    width: 5em;
    height: 25em;
    float: left;
    border-width: 0.1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom: #ffba00 solid 0.5em;
}
```

If anyone can see the problem in this, please let me know.

I thank you for your time.

Yonker

Comment: What does it do when you remove the base css border-bottom: attribute?

Comment: Created a jsfiddle with your code, and it changes the boarder as expected:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DV2Rq/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your first .animate() - use .end() before moving on.  This tells it to go back to the original selector (this), which could be the culprit.  Otherwise, it will use siblings() as the current selector.

Comment: God i love stackoverflow. Thanks a lot... Even thought it probably was a pretty st00pid question, you helped me a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.  Not a stupid question.  It's pretty easy to forget to use .end().

Answer (score 3):

Try to `.end()` the chain

```
$('.Hoofdstuk').click(
    function(){
        $(this)
            .animate({'width': '55em'}).siblings().animate({'width':'5em'}).end()
            .css({'border-color':'#ffba00'}).siblings().css({'border-color':'#333'})

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p5F6S/)

Answer (score 0):

Without `end()` you can as an alternative keep them in order and do it like this:

```
$('.Hoofdstuk').click(function () {
    $(this)
    .animate({'width': '55em'})
    .css({'border-color': '#333'})
    .siblings().animate({'width': '5em'})
    .css({'border-color': '#ffba00'})
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TKVXd/embedded/result/) - this first then siblings

---